# How call this method in a Intent?

Tags: java, android

What I have: I have a RecyclerView with images and each one of this images has an OnClickListener and an Intent

What I want: I want to trigger a method (MethodIwantToCall) that is inside of another Activity when one of this pictures is clicked

My question: How can I trigger this method on an Intent? Please, I would really appreciate the answers with code example, I am new programming and there are many things I don't understand, thanks in advance

Activity with the method I want to call

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        MethodIwantToCall();
    }


public void MethodIwantToCall(){

            String Restaurant = "restaurant";
                mMap.clear();
                String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, Restaurant);
                Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
                DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
                DataTransfer[1] = url;
                Log.d("onClick", url);
                GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
                getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Nearby Restaurants", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

My RecyclerView adapter and where I want to call this method

```
 public class AdapterDatos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDatos.ViewHolder> {

 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.etiNombre.setText(listalugares.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.foto.setImageResource(listalugares.get(position).getFoto());

        holder.foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (position == 0){
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(myIntent);

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a [basic example of what you can do](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#kotlin). Also, [see this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle this by putting extras to your target activity's intent and, to make things easier, you can create a static method in your target activity that will return an intent to that activity with the previously mentioned extra.

Here is an example:

```
// --- MapsActivity ---
private static final String EXTRA_TRIGGER_METHOD = "trigger_method";

public static Intent getIntent(Context context, boolean triggerMethod) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TRIGGER_METHOD, triggerMethod);
    return intent;
}

private boolean triggerMethod;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // here we will assign to triggerMethod the value you passed to the intent when we started this activity
    triggerMethod = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_TRIGGER_METHOD, false);

    if (triggerMethod) {
        methodIWantToCall();
    }
}

// --- AdapterDatos ---
holder.foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (position == 0) {
            final boolean triggerMethod = true;
            Intent intent = MapsActivity.getIntent(context, triggerMethod);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```